# `componentDidUpdate()` not triggering on a different tab/screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am developing a small game (similar to tictactoe) in React which uses `socket.io`. He is a description of a scenario were a player makes a move:

1. Move is sent to the server by emitting a `game-move` event (from the react client).
2. Server updates local board array then emits an event containing a copy of the board to the clients(s) via a `${gameId}-board` event (clients listen based on the gameId they have).
3. Upon, the client(s), receiving the event, they update the board with the move played before step one and this reflects on the screen.

The issue is I only see the changes on the screen of the player who played the move and wanted to updated all clients that are in that game (subscribed to the gameId). In other words, updates are only occurring if either person makes a move.

I am using `componentDidUpdate()` which uses a socket connection to receive events and update the state but for some reason the problem I mentioned above is happening and would appreciate some input. Below is the code for what I just described (minus the server and other components as those are working fine):

```
class Board extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(6).fill([]).map(() => Array(7).fill(null)),
            errorOccured: false,
            errorMessage: "",
            gameId: "",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        ...
    }

    componentDidUpdate(): void {
        // @NOTE: This is not triggering on a different tab/screen
        socketConnection.on(`${this.state.gameId}-board`, (message) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(message);
            this.handleMessage(data);
        });
    }

    handleMessage(data: any) {
        if(data && data.errorOccured) {
            this.setState({errorOccured: true, errorMessage: data.errorMessage});
        } else if(data && !data.errorOccured) {
            let updatedBoard = data.game.gameState

            this.setState({
                board: updatedBoard
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({errorOccured: true, errorMessage: "An error occurred, please try again."});
        }
    }

    handleMove(column: number) {
        let isValid = this.isMoveValid(column);

        if(!isValid) {
            this.setState({
                errorOccured: true,
                errorMessage: "Invalid Move!"
            })
        } else {
            socketConnection.emit(`game-move`, 
                ...
            );
        }
    }

    renderSquare(row: number, col: number, key: number) {
        return (
            <Square
                key = { key }
                value = { this.state.squares[row][col] }
                onClick = { () => this.handleMove(col) }
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const status = "Current Player: " + ( this.state.xIsNext ? '' : '' );
        let square = 0;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                {
                    this.state.squares.map((row: any, rowIndex: number) => 
                        (
                            <div className="row" key={rowIndex} >
                                {
                                    (row.map((value: any, colIndex: number) => (
                                        this.renderSquare(rowIndex, colIndex, square++)
                                    )))
                                }
                            </div>
                        )
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Board;
```

Please don't worry/focus about the design, I am simply using this tiny project as an introduction to React.

Comment: What do you think `componentDidUpdate` do? The code you have in the body of that function should be in `componentDidMount`. `componentDidMount` will add a new listener every time you change a state or a prop

Comment: Are you sure that `handleMessage` is not called?

Comment: @Konrad it is being called but changes to the state are only being applied on the screen where the move was played, the other screen/tab remains idle.

Comment: So maybe `data.game.gameState` has an old game state value?

Comment: @Konrad This is the only place where the state of the board is updated, if that were true the changes would not reflect on the screen of the user who played. Also debugged and confirmed the `gameState` is up to date (has latest value).

Comment: The only two things I can think of are that you use `squares` for rendering, but assing to `board`. And the listener should be in `componentDidMount` so it's not added multiple times